# Is it haram to put pictures of the part of female body without the face?

Tags: halal-haram, women, image

Is it haram to put pictures of the part of Muslim female body in order to show the shoes like the picture below?
The picture is NOT to show the body itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the part of the body shown is part of the awrah of a woman and is bare, then it is obviously not permitted to show it to non-mahrams males.

Comment: Salam, Would this be permissable if its the lips or arms, etc. Say you aren't showing it to men and it is simply for decor on your wallls, would that be haram? Because I have heard that hanging up a picture with of a human or animal is haram, so what it bould be permissable if it was only part of someone? Thanks.